# Как установить цвет любого пиксела на экране без winApi?

Tags: delphi, gdi

Как можно быстро изменять цвет произвольной точки экрана? Ведь ВинАпи функции прежде, чем сделать это, высчитывают  какие-то координаты или ещё что-то, а потом меняют цвет точки (setpixel(), например)... Но именно изменение цвета пиксела, как? Может где-то в памяти хранится текущий массив точек экрана (возможно, в видео памяти), как манипулировать этим массивом?

Comment: Не уверен, но возможно вам помогут аппаратные оверлеи.

Comment: А для чего это нужно кстати?

Если нужно изменить только один пиксель, то достаточно SetPixel(), а если нужно изменить какую-то прямоугольную область - можно скопировать ее в память (memory DC), ассоциировать с DIB-section, к которому уже можно обращаться уже как к массиву пикселей, а потом скопировать эту область обратно.

Comment: а приведите пожалуста пример

Comment: Сегодня не получится, напишу завтра

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
program ScreenDIBDots;

uses Windows;

type
  RGBarray = array[0..0] of COLORREF;

var
  i,width,height:integer;
  ScreenDC,MemoryDC:HDC;
  Dib:HBITMAP;
  bmi:BITMAPINFO;
  bits:pointer;
  rgbs:^RGBarray;

begin
  ScreenDC := GetDC(0);

  // Определяем размеры экрана:
  width := GetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC,HORZRES);
  height := GetDeviceCaps(ScreenDC,VERTRES);

  // Создаем контекст памяти совместимый с контекстом экрана:
  MemoryDC := CreateCompatibleDC(ScreenDC);

  // Подготовка структуры BITMAPINFO:
  with bmi.bmiHeader do
  begin
    biSize := SizeOf(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    biWidth := width;
    biHeight := -height; // минус нужен для прямого порядка строк
    biPlanes := 1;
    biBitCount := 32;
    biCompression := BI_RGB;
    biSizeImage := 0;
    biXPelsPerMeter := 12500;
    biYPelsPerMeter := 12500;
    biClrUsed := 0;
    biClrImportant := 0;
  end;
  Dib := CreateDIBSection(ScreenDC,bmi,DIB_RGB_COLORS,bits,0,0); // Создаем DIBSection
  rgbs := bits;
  SelectObject(MemoryDC,Dib); // Выбираем DIBSection в контекст памяти

  // Копирование изображения из контекста экрана в контекст памяти:
  BitBlt(MemoryDC,0,0,width,height,ScreenDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);

  // Попиксельное изменение изображения в памяти:
  randomize;
  for i:=1 to 100000 do
    rgbs^[random(width*height)] :=
      RGB(Random(256) {синий}, Random(256) {зеленый}, Random(256) {красный});

  // Копирование изображения обратно в контекст экрана
  BitBlt(ScreenDC,0,0,width,height,MemoryDC,0,0,SRCCOPY);

  // Освобождение объектов
  ReleaseDC(0,ScreenDC);
  DeleteDC(MemoryDC);
  DeleteObject(Dib);
end.
```

В общем случае индекс в массиве rgbs определяется так: x+width*y (x и y отсчитываются от 0)

Comment: то-что нужно! работает быстро!!! спс

Answer (score 0):

Может этот пример подойдёт? Программа работает в фоновом режиме (выход на Esc) ставит точки на экране произвольного цвета и в произвольном месте.

```
program ScreenDotsProject;

uses
  Windows, // для доступа к экрану
  Forms, // для взятия размеров экрана
  Graphics; // для графики (канвы, цветов)

Var
  ScreenDC: HDC;
  ScreenCanvas: TCanvas;
  Esc: SmallInt;

begin
  Esc:=GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE);
  ScreenDC:=GetDC(0);
  ScreenCanvas:=TCanvas.Create;
  ScreenCanvas.Handle:=ScreenDC;

  Randomize;
  Repeat
    ScreenCanvas.Pixels[Random(Screen.Width), 
      Random(Screen.Height)]:=RGB(Random(256), Random(256), Random(256));
  Until (Esc<>GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE));

  ReleaseDC(0, ScreenDC);
  ScreenCanvas.Free;
end.
```

Comment: нет. долго.

Comment: Tcanvas.pixels это есть надстройка над  WinApi функцией setpixels(), поэтому работает очень долго

Comment: Как быстрее не знаю - меня это всегда устраивало. А для чего очень высокая скорость требуется (просто интересно)?

Comment: тогда вам, видимо, надо лезть на уровень драйвера видеокарты

Comment: высокая скорость нужна для наложения тестур причем несколько наложений в секунду. но используя только cpu

Answer (score 0):

```
Canvas.Pixels[random(500),random(500)]:= clRed
```

Comment: Вы хоть тему прочитали? 

> Tcanvas.pixels это есть надстройка над WinApi функцией setpixels(), поэтому работает очень долго