# Почему не рисует bmp на окне ?

Tags: delphi, графика

```
     //hCurDC:=getdc(form1.handle);

      var

        hbmp: HBITMAP;      
        bmi: BITMAPINFO;    
        pvBits: Pointer;    
        x,y: integer;
 begin

with bmi.bmiHeader do
begin
  biSize         := sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
  biWidth        := 100;
  biHeight       := 100;
  biPlanes       := 1;
  biBitCount     := 24;   // 24 pf  (r,g,b)
  biCompression  := BI_RGB;
  biSizeImage    := 100*100*3;
end;

hbmp := CreateDIBSection(hCurDC, bmi, DIB_RGB_COLORS, pvBits, 0, 0);
SelectObject(hCurDC, hbmp);

   for x := 1 to 50 do
   for y := 1 to 50 do

  PULONG(Integer(pvBits) +
          (x + y ) * sizeof(ULONG))^ :=$0000ff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Само рисование выполняется при вызове функции [BitBlt](http://www.delphiexpert.ru/view_winapi.php?id=23). См. второй вызов функции в моем ответе [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/62261/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%86%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%8D%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7-winapi).

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, ты ЭТО имеешь ввиду :

```
> var bmp:Tbitmap;   
> begin 
> bmp:=Tbitmap.Create; 
> bmp.canvas.Handle:=getdc(0);       // получаем контекст(HDC) рабочего стола 
> bmp.canvas.Rectangle(0,0,200,100); // А далее рисуем, как в обычном TbitMap`е =)
```

Comment: нет, я не ЭТО имею ввиду, я описываю бмп и вывожу на окно

Comment: То есть ты хочешь рисовать в чужом окне, как в битмапе?

Comment: Не совсем. Я хочу выводить в окно картинку как здесь: [альфа-смешивание](http://f1-delphi.ru/books/delphi_tryuki_i_effekty/6_9_alfa_smeshivanie/).

Comment: Ну вы планируете использовать такой алгоритм:

1) Получить дескриптор окна и его контекст

2) Создать битмап и присвоить ему контекст, полученного окна.

3) Вывести туда рисунок

Так?

Comment: Да. Только битмап должен выглядить как тут:

http://f1-delphi.ru/books/delphi_tryuki_i_effekty/6_9_alfa_smeshivanie/  
 А не TBTIMAP