# Как ускорить GetPixel?

Tags: c++

Как ускорить функцию GetPixel? Может есть какая-то альтернатива?
Мне нужно получать цвет пикселя в середине экрана (или приложения).

Comment: Для получения одного пиксела- никак не ускорить, наверное.

Comment: Если нужно обращаться ко многим пикселям, можно скопировать изображение из контекста экрана в MemoryDC (контекст памяти), потом к MemoryDC привязать DIBSection, а потом к отдельным пикселям внутри DIBSection обращаться как к элементам массива ([как в этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/62956/1365), только чтение из массива вместо записи, и обратно копировать не нужно, там на Delphi, но на С++ суть будет та же). Можно еще попробовать привязать DIBSection напрямую к контексту экрана (без промежуточного MemoryDC), но вроде бы это так не работало.

Comment: Если очень-очень сильно хочется, можно пойти по технологии захвата экрана, которую использует [Looking Glass](https://looking-glass.io/) (захват экрана через DirectX), но для единственного пикселя усилия могут не оправдаться.